# How do you figure out other __label fields to filter by in Python

Tags: python, django

I have the following code which works,

```
for x in SomeModel.objects.filter(type__label='ABC'):
```

Now 'ABC' is one of the labels. How do I find out what other labels I can filter by?

Comment: Have you looked at the models in the admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. The possible values of `type__label` are the values in the `label` field of (presumably) the `Type` model. You could get a list of those:

```
Type.objects.values_list('label', flat=True)
```

or, as David suggests in the comment, just look in the admin interface.

Comment: David's suggestion to look in the admin interface was useful. It had all the other labels.